# Temporary URL for an asynchronous API

Tags: api, rest, asynchronous, hunchentoot

I am designing an asynchronous API according to the RESTful principles set out [here](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/06/02/asynchronous-operations-in-rest/). This involves a temporary URL, specified in the response's `Location` header, which clients can poll for status updates until their result is ready. I've never dealt with temporary URLs before, so how might I go about building one? We are using the Hunchentoot (Common Lisp) webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect that URL to be temporary. That shows the status of the creation request. When creation is done, the response from that URL would indicate `<status>done</status>` or somesuch. If you really want to pull that URL (which I don't recommend), then you would return a 404.

Comment: Thank you (sorry not to reply sooner on this). Indeed we have decided to maintain a permanent endpoint for this.